# VBScript Type Mismatch

Tags: vbscript, types, type-mismatch

I have a type mismatch in my VBScript script. I know that the value is correct, but not sure why it's coming up.

This is the line where the script terminates:

```
WScript.Echo "DNS Server Search Order: " & objNicItem.DNSServerSearchOrder
```

The script requires a file named `servers.txt` (which has a list of servers in it, I am tesing using my own workstation name).

If I do an `error on resume next` the script works. However if the servers list is populated. it displays the same information as the fisrt which works again for each host, so it's not correct.

```
'Input from the command line
If Wscript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Usage: DNSAudit.vbs servers.txt "
    Wscript.Quit
End If

'Input from txt file
Const ForReading = 1
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ObjArgs(0), ForReading)
i = 0
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    StrNextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
    objDictionary.Add i, StrNextLine
    i = i + 1
Loop
For Each objItem In objDictionary
    Computer = objDictionary.Item(objItem)

    'For Each Computer In Wscript.Arguments

    'remote connection to another computer other than using variables
    'Set ObjWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts://COMPUTERNAME") for remote connection

    Set ObjWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & Computer & "\root\cimv2")
    'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo "**************************************************************"  & vbCrLf
    'WScript.Echo "Connection Errors"  & vbCrLf
    'WScript.Echo Computer & " " & Err.Description
    'WScript.Echo Computer & " " & Err.Description & " investigation required!"
    'WScript.Echo "**************************************************************"  & vbCrLf
    ''*********************************************************************************************************
    'End if
    WScript.Echo "**************************************************************"  & vbCrLf
    WScript.Echo "Starting Audit on " & computer
    WScript.Echo "**************************************************************"  & vbCrLf
    WScript.Echo "**************************************************************"  & vbCrLf
    wscript.echo "List DHCP, DNS, WINS Adapter Parameters"
    wscript.Echo "**************************************************************"  & vbCrLf

    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

    For Each objNicItem in colItems
        Wscript.Echo "DHCP Enabled: " & objNicItem.DHCPEnabled
        Wscript.Echo "DHCP Lease Expires: " & objNicItem.DHCPLeaseExpires
        Wscript.Echo "DHCP Lease Obtained: " & objNicItem.DHCPLeaseObtained
        Wscript.Echo "DHCP Server: " & objNicItem.DHCPServer
        Wscript.Echo "DNS Domain: " & objNicItem.DNSDomain
        Wscript.Echo "DNS Domain Suffix Search Order: " & _
            objNicItem.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
        Wscript.Echo "DNS Enabled For WINS Resolution: " & _
            objNicItem.DNSEnabledForWINSResolution
        Wscript.Echo "DNS Host Name: " & objNicItem.DNSHostName
        WScript.Echo "DNS Server Search Order: " & objNicItem.DNSServerSearchOrder
    WScript.Echo "Domain DNS Registration Enabled: " & objNicItem.DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled
        Wscript.Echo "Full DNS Registration Enabled: " & _
            objNicItem.FullDNSRegistrationEnabled
       Wscript.Echo "IP Address: " & objNicItem.IPAddress
       Wscript.Echo "MAC Address: " & objNicItem.MACAddress
        Wscript.Echo "TCP Maximum Data Retransmissions: " & _
            objNicItem.TcpMaxDataRetransmissions
        Wscript.Echo "TCP NumC onnections: " & objNicItem.TcpNumConnections
        Wscript.Echo "WINS Host Lookup File: " & objNicItem.WINSHostLookupFile
        Wscript.Echo "WINS Primary Server: " & objNicItem.WINSPrimaryServer
        Wscript.Echo "WINS Secondary Server: " & objNicItem.WINSSecondaryServer & vbCrLf
        Wscript.Echo "Adaptor: "  & objNicItem.Description & vbCrLf
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fully working now with the following code:

```
Wscript.Echo "IP Address: " & objNicItem.IPAddress(0)
```

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that DNSServerSearchOrder is a list of key/value pairs so the Echo command will fail. You will need to enumerate through all the values like this:

```
If Not IsNull(objNicItem.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then
  For x = 0 To UBound(objNicItem.DNSServerSearchOrder)
     WScript.Echo "      " & objNicItem.DNSServerSearchOrder(x)
  Next
End If
```

Comment: Or: `For Each strDNS in objNicItem.DNSServerSearchOrder : WScript.Echo " " & strDNS : Next` (Colons due to absence of line break in comments.)

Answer (score 3):

The `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` object's `DNSServerSearchOrder` property is an array, not a value that can be (implicitly) converted to a string.

See [MSDN on the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Try escaping the parenthesis with the backslash: `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: +1 - Link fixed. <hint>The "Hyperlink" button in the editor does a good job escaping links to an SO-compatible format.</hint> ;-)

Comment: @Helen: This would break it even more. Not everything can be escaped with backslashes. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak: Backslash is a Markdown escape character for special characters, including parenthesis in link addresses within the `[...](...)` constructs (see http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash). So the `\(` and `\)` escapes are turned into literal parenthesis in the resulting link address. Worked just fine with all MSDN links I've posted on SO so far. :)

Comment: @Helen: Thanks for the hint! :) I didn't know, obviously. Shame on me.

Comment: @Tomalak: please refund me my thanks; @Helen: please accept this slightly-used thanks :-)  [Seriously, thankyou both]